# Viewing export table on an unmanaged dll in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke, dbghelp

I am currently trying to create a C# application that will allow me to view the export table from an unmanaged DLL. My problem is, once I have all the pointers I need, I have no idea how to loop through the information that the API has provided me. Here is what I have right now:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DLLMapper
{
class DLLExportViewer
{
        #region APIs
        [DllImport("imagehlp.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean MapAndLoad(String ImageName, String DllPath, ref LOADED_IMAGE LoadedImage, Boolean DotDll, Boolean ReadOnly);

        [DllImport("imagehlp.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean UnMapAndLoad(ref LOADED_IMAGE LoadedImage);

        [DllImport("dbghelp.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ImageDirectoryEntryToData(IntPtr Base, Boolean MappedAsImage, UInt16 DirectoryEntry, ref Int32 Size);

        [DllImport("dbghelp.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ImageRvaToVa(ref IMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders, IntPtr Base, UInt32 Rva, ref IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER LastRvaSection);
        #endregion

        #region Structures
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct LOADED_IMAGE
        {
            public String ModuleName;
            public IntPtr hFile;
            public IntPtr MappedAddress;
            public IMAGE_NT_HEADERS FileHeader;
            public IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER LastRvaSection;
            public Int32 NumberOfSections;
            public IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Sections;
            public Int32 Characteristics;
            public Boolean fSystemImage;
            public Boolean fDOSImage;
            public LIST_ENTRY Links;
            public Int32 SizeOfImage;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY
        {
            public UInt32 Characteristics;
            public UInt32 TimeDateStamp;
            public UInt16 MajorVersion;
            public UInt16 MinorVersion;
            public UInt32 Name;
            public UInt32 Base;
            public UInt32 NumberOfFunctions;
            public UInt32 NumberOfNames;
            public UInt32 AddressOfFunctions;
            public UInt32 AddressOfNames;
            public UInt32 AddressOfOrdinals;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct IMAGE_NT_HEADERS
        {
            public Int32 Signature;
            public IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader;
            public IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER OptionalHeader;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct LIST_ENTRY
        {
            public IntPtr Flink;
            public IntPtr Blink;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME)]
            public Byte[] Name;
            public Misc Misc;
            public UInt32 PhysicalAddress;
            public UInt32 VirtualAddress;
            public UInt32 SizeOfRawData;
            public UInt32 PointerToRawData;
            public UInt32 PointerToRelocations;
            public UInt32 PointerToLinenumbers;
            public Int16 NumberOfRelocations;
            public Int16 NumberOfLinenumbers;
            public UInt32 Characteristics;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
        {
            public UInt16 Machine;
            public UInt16 NumberOfSections;
            public UInt32 TimeDateStamp;
            public UInt32 PointerToSymbolTable;
            public UInt32 NumberOfSymbols;
            public UInt16 SizeOfOptionalHeader;
            public UInt16 Characteristics;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER
        {
            public UInt16 Magic;
            public Byte MajorLinkerVersion;
            public Byte MinorLinkerVersion;
            public UInt32 SizeOfCode;
            public UInt32 SizeOfInitializedData;
            public UInt32 SizeOfUninitializedData;
            public UInt32 AddressOfEntryPoint;
            public UInt32 BaseOfCode;
            public UInt32 BaseOfData;
            public UInt32 ImageBase;
            public UInt32 SectionAlignment;
            public UInt32 FileAlignment;
            public UInt16 MajorOperatingSystemVersion;
            public UInt16 MinorOperatingSystemVersion;
            public UInt16 MajorImageVersion;
            public UInt16 MinorImageVersion;
            public UInt16 MajorSubsystemVersion;
            public UInt16 MinorSubsystemVersion;
            public UInt32 Win32VersionValue;
            public UInt32 SizeOfImage;
            public UInt32 SizeOfHeaders;
            public UInt32 CheckSum;
            public UInt16 Subsystem;
            public UInt16 DllCharacteristics;
            public UInt32 SizeOfStackReserve;
            public UInt32 SizeOfStackCommit;
            public UInt32 SizeOfHeapReserve;
            public UInt32 SizeOfHeapCommit;
            public UInt32 LoaderFlags;
            public UInt32 NumberOfRvaAndSizes;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES)]
            public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY[] DataDirectory;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
        {
            public UInt32 VirtualAddress;
            public UInt32 Size;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct Misc
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public UInt32 PhysicalAddress;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public UInt32 VirtualSize;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Variables & Constants
        public const Int32 IMAGE_SIZEOF_SHORT_NAME = 8;
        public const Int32 IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES = 16;
        public const UInt16 IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// String value holding the path to the DLL file. This value is also returned by the FileName property.
        /// </summary>
        private String sDLLFilePath;

        /// <summary>
        /// Boolean value that is return by the LibraryLoaded property.
        /// </summary>
        private Boolean bLibraryLoaded;

        /// <summary>
        /// Int32 value that is returned by the FunctionCount property.
        /// </summary>
        private Int32 iFunctionCount;

        /// <summary>
        /// Int32 value that is returned by the SizeOfImage property.
        /// </summary>
        private Int32 iSizeOfCode;

        /// <summary>
        /// String array value that is returned by the ImageFunctions property.
        /// </summary>
        private String[] sFunctions;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a boolean value indicating if the library has been loaded successfully.
        /// </summary>
        public Boolean LibraryLoaded { get { return bLibraryLoaded; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a string value indicating what file the class was initialized with.
        /// </summary>
        public String FileName { get { return sDLLFilePath; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a string array of the functions within the image.
        /// </summary>
        public String[] ImageFunctions { get { return sFunctions; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an Int32 value indicating the number of functions within the image.
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 FunctionCount { get { return iFunctionCount; } }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Initilizes the DLLExportViewer class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sFilePath">Path to the DLL file to initilize the class with.</param>
        public DLLExportViewer(String sFilePath)
        {
            IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER ishSectionHeader = new IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER();
            LOADED_IMAGE liLoadedImage = new LOADED_IMAGE();
            IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY iedExportDirectory;
            IntPtr pImageExportDirectory;
            IntPtr pVirtualAddressOfNames;
            Int32 iDirectoryExportSize = 0;

            sDLLFilePath = sFilePath;

            if (MapAndLoad(sDLLFilePath, null, ref liLoadedImage, true, true))
            {
                bLibraryLoaded = true;

                pImageExportDirectory = ImageDirectoryEntryToData(liLoadedImage.MappedAddress, false, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT, ref iDirectoryExportSize);
                iedExportDirectory = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pImageExportDirectory, typeof(IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY));

                iFunctionCount = (Int32)iedExportDirectory.NumberOfFunctions;

                pVirtualAddressOfNames = ImageRvaToVa(ref liLoadedImage.FileHeader, liLoadedImage.MappedAddress, iedExportDirectory.AddressOfNames, ref ishSectionHeader);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to load library {0}\n\nError Number:{1]\nError:{2}", sDLLFilePath, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My biggest concern is that I may have some of the marshalling on the structures wrong. But, all in all, I'm not sure where to go from here. Can anyone offer me some assistance?

Comment: You are re-inventing a wheel.  Use Dumpbin.exe /exports

Comment: I know I am re-inventing the wheel. I am trying to learn how to do it, and not just use another utility.

Comment: @dotNetNinja Please change your user name - if you were a dotNetNinja you'd be answering this question rather than asking it!  ;-)

Comment: Isn't it kinda of the point to figure this out by yourself then?  Try tagging with [homework] so you don't get the solution dropped in your lap.  Albeit it isn't very likely considering the wall of code.

Comment: Not sure why you all believe I should mark it as homework, being that it is not homework, and I am just trying to learn some indepth p/invoke on some functions that are not documented very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437432/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-the-functions-exposed-by-a-dll

Comment: I recommend you write and debug a small unmanaged version of your program in C++.  Once that is working with known inputs and outputs, then you can go back to C# and interop, knowing exactly what results you should expect.

Answer (score 2):

The following shows how to do it using p/invoke to dbghelp. Note that I used a number of declarations from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.ComponentModel;

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [Flags]
    public enum EFileAccess : uint
    {
        //
        // Standard Section
        //

        AccessSystemSecurity = 0x1000000,   // AccessSystemAcl access type
        MaximumAllowed = 0x2000000,     // MaximumAllowed access type

        Delete = 0x10000,
        ReadControl = 0x20000,
        WriteDAC = 0x40000,
        WriteOwner = 0x80000,
        Synchronize = 0x100000,

        StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
        StandardRightsRead = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsWrite = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsExecute = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsAll = 0x1F0000,
        SpecificRightsAll = 0xFFFF,

        FILE_READ_DATA = 0x0001,        // file & pipe
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001,       // directory
        FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x0002,       // file & pipe
        FILE_ADD_FILE = 0x0002,         // directory
        FILE_APPEND_DATA = 0x0004,      // file
        FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY = 0x0004,     // directory
        FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE = 0x0004, // named pipe
        FILE_READ_EA = 0x0008,          // file & directory
        FILE_WRITE_EA = 0x0010,         // file & directory
        FILE_EXECUTE = 0x0020,          // file
        FILE_TRAVERSE = 0x0020,         // directory
        FILE_DELETE_CHILD = 0x0040,     // directory
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0080,      // all
        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0100,     // all

        //
        // Generic Section
        //

        GenericRead = 0x80000000,
        GenericWrite = 0x40000000,
        GenericExecute = 0x20000000,
        GenericAll = 0x10000000,

        SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x00FFFF,
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS =
        StandardRightsRequired |
        Synchronize |
        0x1FF,

        FILE_GENERIC_READ =
        StandardRightsRead |
        FILE_READ_DATA |
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES |
        FILE_READ_EA |
        Synchronize,

        FILE_GENERIC_WRITE =
        StandardRightsWrite |
        FILE_WRITE_DATA |
        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES |
        FILE_WRITE_EA |
        FILE_APPEND_DATA |
        Synchronize,

        FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE =
        StandardRightsExecute |
          FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES |
          FILE_EXECUTE |
          Synchronize
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum EFileShare : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        None = 0x00000000,
        /// <summary>
        /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request read access. 
        /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request read access. 
        /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for read access, the function fails.
        /// </summary>
        Read = 0x00000001,
        /// <summary>
        /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request write access. 
        /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request write access. 
        /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for write access, the function fails.
        /// </summary>
        Write = 0x00000002,
        /// <summary>
        /// Enables subsequent open operations on an object to request delete access. 
        /// Otherwise, other processes cannot open the object if they request delete access.
        /// If this flag is not specified, but the object has been opened for delete access, the function fails.
        /// </summary>
        Delete = 0x00000004
    }

    public enum ECreationDisposition : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new file. The function fails if a specified file exists.
        /// </summary>
        New = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new file, always. 
        /// If a file exists, the function overwrites the file, clears the existing attributes, combines the specified file attributes, 
        /// and flags with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, but does not set the security descriptor that the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure specifies.
        /// </summary>
        CreateAlways = 2,
        /// <summary>
        /// Opens a file. The function fails if the file does not exist. 
        /// </summary>
        OpenExisting = 3,
        /// <summary>
        /// Opens a file, always. 
        /// If a file does not exist, the function creates a file as if dwCreationDisposition is CREATE_NEW.
        /// </summary>
        OpenAlways = 4,
        /// <summary>
        /// Opens a file and truncates it so that its size is 0 (zero) bytes. The function fails if the file does not exist.
        /// The calling process must open the file with the GENERIC_WRITE access right. 
        /// </summary>
        TruncateExisting = 5
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum EFileAttributes : uint
    {
        Readonly = 0x00000001,
        Hidden = 0x00000002,
        System = 0x00000004,
        Directory = 0x00000010,
        Archive = 0x00000020,
        Device = 0x00000040,
        Normal = 0x00000080,
        Temporary = 0x00000100,
        SparseFile = 0x00000200,
        ReparsePoint = 0x00000400,
        Compressed = 0x00000800,
        Offline = 0x00001000,
        NotContentIndexed = 0x00002000,
        Encrypted = 0x00004000,
        Write_Through = 0x80000000,
        Overlapped = 0x40000000,
        NoBuffering = 0x20000000,
        RandomAccess = 0x10000000,
        SequentialScan = 0x08000000,
        DeleteOnClose = 0x04000000,
        BackupSemantics = 0x02000000,
        PosixSemantics = 0x01000000,
        OpenReparsePoint = 0x00200000,
        OpenNoRecall = 0x00100000,
        FirstPipeInstance = 0x00080000
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string lpFileName,
        EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
        EFileShare dwShareMode,
        IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
        ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
        EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile
    );

    [Flags]
    public enum FileMapProtection : uint
    {
        PageReadonly = 0x02,
        PageReadWrite = 0x04,
        PageWriteCopy = 0x08,
        PageExecuteRead = 0x20,
        PageExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
        SectionCommit = 0x8000000,
        SectionImage = 0x1000000,
        SectionNoCache = 0x10000000,
        SectionReserve = 0x4000000,
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFileMapping(
        SafeFileHandle hFile,
        IntPtr lpFileMappingAttributes,
        FileMapProtection flProtect,
        uint dwMaximumSizeHigh,
        uint dwMaximumSizeLow,
        string lpName
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFileMapping(
        SafeFileHandle hFile,
        IntPtr lpFileMappingAttributes,
        FileMapProtection flProtect,
        uint dwMaximumSizeHigh,
        uint dwMaximumSizeLow,
        IntPtr lpName
    );

    [Flags]
    public enum FileMapAccess : uint
    {
        FileMapCopy = 0x0001,
        FileMapWrite = 0x0002,
        FileMapRead = 0x0004,
        FileMapAllAccess = 0x001f,
        FileMapExecute = 0x0020,
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr MapViewOfFile(
        SafeFileHandle hFileMappingObject,
        FileMapAccess dwDesiredAccess,
        UInt32 dwFileOffsetHigh,
        UInt32 dwFileOffsetLow,
        UIntPtr dwNumberOfBytesToMap
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UnmapViewOfFile(IntPtr lpBaseAddress);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
    {
        public UInt16 Machine;
        public UInt16 NumberOfSections;
        public UInt32 TimeDateStamp;
        public UInt32 PointerToSymbolTable;
        public UInt32 NumberOfSymbols;
        public UInt16 SizeOfOptionalHeader;
        public UInt16 Characteristics;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY
    {
        public UInt32 VirtualAddress;
        public UInt32 Size;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER
    {
        public UInt16 Magic;
        public Byte MajorLinkerVersion;
        public Byte MinorLinkerVersion;
        public UInt32 SizeOfCode;
        public UInt32 SizeOfInitializedData;
        public UInt32 SizeOfUninitializedData;
        public UInt32 AddressOfEntryPoint;
        public UInt32 BaseOfCode;
        public UInt32 BaseOfData;
        public UInt32 ImageBase;
        public UInt32 SectionAlignment;
        public UInt32 FileAlignment;
        public UInt16 MajorOperatingSystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorOperatingSystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MajorImageVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorImageVersion;
        public UInt16 MajorSubsystemVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorSubsystemVersion;
        public UInt32 Win32VersionValue;
        public UInt32 SizeOfImage;
        public UInt32 SizeOfHeaders;
        public UInt32 CheckSum;
        public UInt16 Subsystem;
        public UInt16 DllCharacteristics;
        public UInt32 SizeOfStackReserve;
        public UInt32 SizeOfStackCommit;
        public UInt32 SizeOfHeapReserve;
        public UInt32 SizeOfHeapCommit;
        public UInt32 LoaderFlags;
        public UInt32 NumberOfRvaAndSizes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY[] DataDirectory;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IMAGE_NT_HEADERS
    {
        public UInt32 Signature;
        public IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader;
        public IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER OptionalHeader;
    }

    [DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr ImageNtHeader(
        IntPtr ImageBase
    );

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY
    {
        public UInt32 Characteristics;
        public UInt32 TimeDateStamp;
        public UInt16 MajorVersion;
        public UInt16 MinorVersion;
        public UInt32 Name;
        public UInt32 Base;
        public UInt32 NumberOfFunctions;
        public UInt32 NumberOfNames;
        public UInt32 AddressOfFunctions;     // RVA from base of image
        public UInt32 AddressOfNames;     // RVA from base of image
        public UInt32 AddressOfNameOrdinals;  // RVA from base of image
    }

    [DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr ImageRvaToVa(
        IntPtr NtHeaders,
        IntPtr Base,
        UInt32 Rva,
        IntPtr LastRvaSection
    );
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string[] GetExports(string ModuleFileName)
        {
            SafeFileHandle FileHandle = NativeMethods.CreateFile(
                ModuleFileName,
                NativeMethods.EFileAccess.GenericRead,
                NativeMethods.EFileShare.Read,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                NativeMethods.ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting,
                NativeMethods.EFileAttributes.Normal,
                IntPtr.Zero
            );
            if (FileHandle.IsInvalid)
                throw new Win32Exception();

            try
            {
                SafeFileHandle ImageHandle = NativeMethods.CreateFileMapping(
                    FileHandle,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    NativeMethods.FileMapProtection.PageReadonly,
                    0,
                    0,
                    IntPtr.Zero
                );
                if (ImageHandle.IsInvalid)
                    throw new Win32Exception();

                try
                {
                    IntPtr ImagePointer = NativeMethods.MapViewOfFile(
                        ImageHandle,
                        NativeMethods.FileMapAccess.FileMapRead,
                        0,
                        0,
                        UIntPtr.Zero
                    );
                    if (ImagePointer == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new Win32Exception();

                    try
                    {
                        IntPtr HeaderPointer = NativeMethods.ImageNtHeader(ImagePointer);
                        if (HeaderPointer == IntPtr.Zero)
                            throw new Win32Exception();

                        NativeMethods.IMAGE_NT_HEADERS Header = (NativeMethods.IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                            HeaderPointer,
                            typeof(NativeMethods.IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)
                        );
                        if (Header.Signature != 0x00004550)// "PE\0\0" as a DWORD
                            throw new Exception(ModuleFileName + " is not a valid PE file");

                        IntPtr ExportTablePointer = NativeMethods.ImageRvaToVa(
                            HeaderPointer,
                            ImagePointer,
                            Header.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[0].VirtualAddress,
                            IntPtr.Zero
                        );
                        if (ExportTablePointer == IntPtr.Zero)
                            throw new Win32Exception();
                        NativeMethods.IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY ExportTable = (NativeMethods.IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                            ExportTablePointer,
                            typeof(NativeMethods.IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)
                        );

                        IntPtr NamesPointer = NativeMethods.ImageRvaToVa(
                            HeaderPointer,
                            ImagePointer,
                            ExportTable.AddressOfNames,
                            IntPtr.Zero
                        );
                        if (NamesPointer == IntPtr.Zero)
                            throw new Win32Exception();

                        NamesPointer = NativeMethods.ImageRvaToVa(
                            HeaderPointer,
                            ImagePointer,
                            (UInt32)Marshal.ReadInt32(NamesPointer),
                            IntPtr.Zero
                        );
                        if (NamesPointer == IntPtr.Zero)
                            throw new Win32Exception();

                        string[] exports = new string[ExportTable.NumberOfNames];
                        for (int i = 0; i < exports.Length; i++)
                        {
                            exports[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(NamesPointer);
                            NamesPointer += exports[i].Length + 1;
                        }

                        return exports;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (!NativeMethods.UnmapViewOfFile(ImagePointer))
                            throw new Win32Exception();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    ImageHandle.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                FileHandle.Close();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string s in GetExports(@"C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not work out for me, ImageRvaToVa returns IntPtr.Zero, resulting in exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the API, I just wrote a class that would parse the PE Header to find the location of the export table. I used the PE file format specification from Microsoft to do this.

[Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/pecoff.mspx)

Comment: That's very nice for you, but no use for anyone else.