# How to loop through all dlls of an exe and see if a certain function is exported

Tags: c#

I have a application which is a game launcher.
While the application is running I want to loop through the dlls which are loaded in that file and check if a certain function is exported.

How can I do that?

I'm not talking about using net reflector I want to check the exported functions by the dlls loaded in the memory from the game launcher and loop through them to see if a certain function is called.

Comment: What do you mean by "exported"?

Comment: Your best bet is to get a copy of .Net Reflector: redgate net reflector

Comment: Via dll viewer I've seen the exported functions of the dll and I want to loop through the dlls when the application is running and check if the program is exporting the function from that dll

Comment: Are you talking about unmanaged or managed DLLs?

Comment: I'm talking about unmanaged dlls

Comment: Every single answer here is wrong.

Comment: Well , you're right but that's because of me because my question was not that clear

Answer (score 1):

Jax, look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606628/viewing-export-table-on-an-unmanaged-dll-in-c-sharp). It should be able to do exactly what you need. To keep things simple, look specifically at the comment that says to use `Dumpbin.exe /exports`. That will probably be the easiest way to do it. If you absolutely need to do it programmically, look at [this Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437432/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-the-functions-exposed-by-a-dll) instead.

Using the Dumpbin method, you could do something like this:

```
        // The name of the DLL to output exports from
        const string dllName = @"C:\Windows\System32\Wdi.dll";
        string output = string.Empty;
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        var process = new Process();

        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.EnvironmentVariables.Remove("Path");
        // DumpBin requires a path to IDE
        info.EnvironmentVariables.Add("Path", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path") + @";c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\");

        // Your path might be different below.
        info.FileName = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\dumpbin.exe";

        info.Arguments = string.Format("/exports \"{0}\"", dllName);

        process.OutputDataReceived += (senderObject, args) => output = output + args.Data;
        process.StartInfo = info;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();
        // output now contains the output
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .net reflection. Here is good sample how to do this:

http://towardsnext.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/listing-types-and-methods-of-assembly-reflection/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at something like

[Using Reflection to load unreferenced assemblies at runtime in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32828/Using-Reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-a)

[Reflection Examples [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/)