# How does java.* libraries implement the Java native interface to use native methods and it's functionalities?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

I wonder how `java.*` libraries implement the `java native interface`?

To be more specific I am investigating the `java.awt.Robot` and come across native method calls. As I am in windows - does that mean there is a `.cpp` file laying around somewhere (inside the `java.awt.*` package?) - that the `java.awt.Robot` uses?

Comment: No, it means there was a .cpp file (likely) and it was compiled into a dll that ships with the Java runtime.

Comment: And most likely it is the file "awt.dll" in the "bin" folder of your JRE.

Comment: You can read about this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_AWT_Native_Interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you call native code, you have to go via JNI. Typically, you need to build shared library. Calling schema follows (note that you don't call C file - it's just visualization of which method will be called):

[image]

So, in a sense, there is a file that contains source code of the library that you call.

In case of Windows, shared libraries are `DLL` files in case of Linux they are typically `so` files and in macOS `dylib`. If you want to make them "visible" to your Java code, you have few options here. You can put location (directory where library is) in:

- `PATH` (windows)
- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (macOS/Linux)
- `-Djava.library.path` - work for all systems, it's just a jvm's argument.

Comment: What is "nm"? - "nm will will show this symbol inside library" -?

Comment: nm is a command in Linux/macOS that shows all symbols inside shared library. I guess, you need to find something that suits your best. E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437432/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-the-functions-exposed-by-a-dll